# I can't seem to center my navbar properly

Tags: html, css

I am currently creating a navbar for my personal website, in the process of making it look decent on mobile I can't seem to center the navbar properly. It leans to the right no matter what I do.[As you can see, it does not align with the pink box above (which is centered correctly)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRIdK.png)

Here is my code for the navbar. I have tried margin and padding properties but they do not have an affect at all inside the @media property. I had also previously made the navbar with flexbox and I ran into the same issue where it leans to the right. I have changed the display to flex INSIDE the @media property and it also leans to the right and neither margin nor padding affect it at all.

```css
.navbar {
  padding: 1px 2px;
  border: 4px double;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 43%;
  margin-right: 43%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: rgba(19, 19, 22, 0.7);
  border-color: white;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3px 13px;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .navbar {
    width: fit-content;
  }
  .navbar ul {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

In my `@media` I have the `width:fit-content` property however if I remove it, it doesn't lean to the right anymore but the text overlaps the border.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It looks to me like something else is affecting its position. Please share additional code for container as well as pink box. The current sample aligns properly as is.

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve finally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some changes to your navbar. First, I wrapped it inside a div with the class d-flex justify-content-center. This helps to center it properly on the page. Then, I removed margins from the navbar class and also removed the @media CSS. Now, your navigation bar should be nicely centered and look good on mobile devices too.

```css
.navbar {
  padding: 1px 2px;
  border: 4px double;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: rgba(19, 19, 22, 0.7);
  border-color: white;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3px 13px;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}
.justify-content-center {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: holy this fixed my issue thank you so much, this is surprisingly a simple way to solve the issue. im not sure how i did not figure this out. thanks

Comment: curious but, i am a beginner, is adding several div classes a practical way? and im still not sure how you managed to make it so the navbar doesn't cover the entire screen

Comment: Using multiple div classes is a common practice in web development and can be very practical for styling and structuring your webpage. By using flexbox or other layout techniques, you can center the navbar horizontally within its parent container. This ensures that it doesn't span the entire width of the screen unless explicitly set to do so.

Answer (score 0):

remove margins on navbar. put following on navbar’s parent:

```
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
```

Comment: It seems I was not specific enough, I apologize. The reason why I have the margins on my navbar were because I do not want the navbar to cover the entire page, I want it to be a small rectangle in the bottom middle of the page, it does fix my issue if it does but that is not what I want.

Comment: I understand, but using margins to set the width of the element may not be the best approach. When you use the flex the child element of the flex will reset to the size of their content instead of covering the whole space like display: block elements do. Give it a try.

Comment: yeah, the guy above actually did what you suggested i think while i completely misunderstood what you said and did something different.